# What is the right way of connecting to a database in Openshift?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, openshift

I'm running a nodejs app along with a PostgreSQL database. Currently, I connect to the database from nodejs with the help of the following environment variables: `POSTGRESQL_HOST`, `POSTGRESQL_USER`, `POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD` and `POSTGRESQL_PORT`. The `POSTGRESQL_USER` and `POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD` are mapped to the right 'secrets'. The port is static, so it never changes. The problem I have is with the host. Currently, I have manually entered the PostgreSQL pod's IP address in `POSTGRESQL_HOST`, but this changes every time the instance is redeployed. What is the right way to connect to the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When setting `POSTGRESQL_HOST` in the environment variables of the deployment configuration, set it to the name of the PostgreSQL database service, not the IP. The name of the service is added as a hostname in an internal DNS server, with it mapping to the appropriate IP. So when the service name is used as hostname, things will resolve automatically.

FWIW, I would personally avoid using the automatically added environment variables. The prefix of those names is the name of the service (in upper case) anyway, so you are already binding it to knowledge of the service name. Better to do that in the deployment configuration using environment variables rather than hardwired into your code. Another problem with the automatically added environment variables will be that they are not set initially if the database is created after the front end. So best to avoid them. They are a legacy of linking containers in docker and they were never that great a way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

If you check your environment with `printenv` from the pod's terminal, you should see the [automatically added variables](https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/environment_variables.html#automatically-added-environment-variables). So, assuming your Postgres service is called `POSTGRES`, you can access your database using the environment variable `POSTGRES_SERVICE_HOST`.

Comment: In such a case, I would need to have `POSTGRES_SERVICE_HOST` in my nodejs app's code rather than the original `POSTGRESQL_HOST` right? Do you know if it is possible to set the value of one environment variable to another? For example, `POSTGRESQL_HOST` = `$POSTGRES_SERVICE_HOST`?

Comment: If you want to still use `POSTGRESQL_HOST`, Graham's answer is the right way to go.